# How to implement simple Monte Carlo function in pymc

Tags: python, pymc

I'm trying to get my head around how to implement a Monte Carlo function in python using pymc to replicate a spreadsheet by Douglas Hubbard in his book [How to Measure Anything](http://www.howtomeasureanything.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HTMA_3rd_Ch6.xlsx)

My attempt was:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pymc import DiscreteUniform, Exponential, deterministic, Poisson, Uniform, Normal, Stochastic, MCMC, Model


maintenance_saving_range = DiscreteUniform('maintenance_saving_range', lower=10, upper=21)
labour_saving_range = DiscreteUniform('labour_saving_range', lower=-2, upper=9)
raw_material_range = DiscreteUniform('maintenance_saving_range', lower=3, upper=10)
production_level_range = DiscreteUniform('maintenance_saving_range', lower=15000, upper=35000)



@deterministic(plot=False)
def rate(m = maintenance_saving_range, l = labour_saving_range, r=raw_material_range, p=production_level_range):
    return (m + l + r) * p

model = Model([rate, maintenance_saving_range, labour_saving_range, raw_material_range, production_level_range])
mc = MCMC(model)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error: `ValueError: A tallyable PyMC object called maintenance_saving_range already exists. This will cause problems for some database backends.`

What have I got wrong?

Comment: PyMC probably has its own object called maintenance_saving_range. Try renaming your variable, for example to my_maintenance_saving_range.

Comment: You were right. Just clumsy copy-paste coding by me.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it was a copy and paste error.

I'd called three distributions by the same name.

Here's the code that works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pymc import DiscreteUniform, Exponential, deterministic, Poisson, Uniform, Normal, Stochastic, MCMC, Model
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

maintenance_saving_range = DiscreteUniform('maintenance_saving_range', lower=10, upper=21)
labour_saving_range = DiscreteUniform('labour_saving_range', lower=-2, upper=9)
raw_material_range = DiscreteUniform('raw_material_range', lower=3, upper=10)
production_level_range = DiscreteUniform('production_level_range', lower=15000, upper=35000)


@deterministic(plot=False, name="rate")
def rate(m = maintenance_saving_range, l = labour_saving_range, r=raw_material_range, p=production_level_range):
    #out = np.empty(10000)
    out = (m + l + r) * p
    return out
model = Model([rate, maintenance_saving_range, labour_saving_range, raw_material_range])
mc = MCMC(model)
mc.sample(iter=10000)
```